# Twitter Bootstrap input-group issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

```
<form class="navbar-form nav-search form-inline" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
         <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm input-search" id="filter-input" placeholder="Type to filter..">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">x</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-search">Search</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XfzFQ/22/

When i use input-group, it is going crazy. I cannot find a solution. Help me!

Comment: It is an issue at bootstrap also.     https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9950
Solution is hacking the bootstrap with giving to form-group style="width:200px".     http://jsfiddle.net/9Z4MN/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue at bootstrap also. [github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9950](http://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9950) Solution is hacking the bootstrap with giving to form-group `style="width:200px"`. [jsfiddle.net/9Z4MN/3](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z4MN/3)

Answer (score 2):

I found the best solution was to correct this within a media query for mobile devices.  This gave me the desired effect on desktops, and 100% width on tablets/phones:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .form-group {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```